# mapreduce.map.java.opts.max.heap and mapreduce.reduce.java.opts.max.heap properties in Cloudera Manager

Tags: hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I have set up a new cluster using Cloudera Manager 5.5.1 , these  2 properties named `mapreduce.map.java.opts.max.heap` and `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts.max.heap` seem ambiguous with the other two properties `mapreduce.map.java.opts` and `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts`.

Should I use the former or the latter set of properties  ?

Answer (score 3):

Both mean the same. The way you specify these values differs.

I guess, `mapreduce.map.java.opts.max.heap` and `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts.max.heap` are specific to Cloudera distribution. Refer: [Tuning YARN](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cdh_ig_yarn_tuning.html).

`mapreduce.map.java.opts` and `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts` are part of standard Hadoop configuration. Check the Hadoop trunk code here: [MrJobConfig.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/MRJobConfig.java)

Also, if you refer to the ticket here: https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/DISTRO-752, it discusses about setting these values.

For e.g. `mapreduce.map.java.opts.max.heap` and `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts.max.heap` are specified as (983 MB):

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts.max.heap</name>
    <value>983</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts.max.heap</name>
    <value>983</value>
</property>
```

`mapreduce.map.java.opts` and `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts` are specified as: (983 MB) (I use these settings)

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx983m</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx983m</value>
</property>
```

Observe the difference in the value. One is set as "983" and the other is set as "-Xmx983m"

Comment: Great answer. If they conflict (have different values e.g. one is global another is set through hive's set parameter), I guess mapreduce.map/reduce.java.opts would win over mapreduce.map/reduce.java.opts.max.heap as they are more generic?

Comment: Yes. mapreduce.map.java.opts and mapreduce.reduce.java.opts are part of standard Hadoop configuration. These "mapreduce.map.java.opts.max.heap and mapreduce.reduce.java.opts.max.heap" seem more specific to Cloudera distribution. I have not seen these parameters in the Hadoop code.

Comment: Also, according to bug you referenced  https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/DISTRO-752 "properties mapreduce.map.java.opts.max.heap, mapreduce.reduce.java.opts.max.heap do not seem to have any effects". So user should go with mapreduce.map/reduce.java.opts=-Xmx until that bug is fixed. I have a case with Cloudera to make sure that's how it works.

Comment: Yes. I use standard Hadoop settings.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use the former or the latter set of properties ?

Answer depends if you use them in CM or not.

If in CM, then mapreduce.map/reduce.java.opts.max.heap are preferable as it's parameter to tune exactly heap of reducers/mappers. mapreduce.map/reducers .java.opts is more generic and if you want to just set heap memory, convoluted as you'll need to add -Xmx too.

If you plan to use anywhere else, then answer is don't use it. As it doesn't exist anywhere except Cloudera Manager. Read comments in https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/DISTRO-752 - Cloudera will most likely remove that parameter name and dix documentation to avoid confusion.